# Android calculate remaining time

Tags: android, time, countdowntimer

I want to do an app in android for example if we program some tasks the app give as notification if the `currenttime=timewespeciefied.`
I have already an array that contain the time the user specified.
the problem here is to calculate the remaining time ! 
is there a class that calculate the remaining time ? 
in my case I have multiple tasks so I must check if the time in the task in the table is already done or not.

```
void LeftTime(){
currenttime.settonow();
            Time LeftTime=new Time();
            for (int i = 0; i <TaskTable.length ; i++) {
                if(currenttime.hour<=TaskTable[i].hour)
                    if(TaskTable.minute==0) LeftTime.minute=60-TaskTable[i].minute;
                if(TaskTable[i].minute<currenttime.minute)
                    LeftTime.minute=currenttime-Tasktable[i].minute;
                            else
                    LeftTime.minute=60-currenttime+Tasktable[i].minute;
            }
```

There is multiple Cases ! How I can do that.

Comment: Can you give an example of the kind of output you want? For example, a `String` that says "1 hour and 43 minutes"?

Comment: For example : the time now 01:10 , the user have a task in 02:03 the output must be : the remaining time is : 0h 53minute @DanS

Comment: it's not what  I want ! I want to calculate the remaining time I have an array that contians for example 5 or 6 tasks (time) , then I must compare the current time with the table of tasks

Comment: Sorry, that was a mistaken click, I have retracted the erroneous vote and removed the mistaken comment.

Comment: it's not a problem thank you for answer !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The family of `String` resulting static functions in [DateUtils](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateUtils.html) can accomplish your task. For example:

```
// Example 1
// Date then; // When the notification will occur
Date now = new Date();
String remaining1 = DateUtils.formatElapsedTime ((then.getTime() - now.getTime())/1000); // Remaining time to seconds
// remaining1: "MM:SS"

// Example 2
String remaining2 = DateUtils.formatElapsedTime (60 * 64 + 8); // 64 minutes in seconds and 8 seconds
// remaining2: "64:08"
```

Comment: Thank you exactly what I'm I searching !

Comment: Says Operator '-' cannot be applied to java.util.Date, java.util.Date. I was calculating the remaining time from a custom date to the current date.

Comment: @DeepakJ Don't forget to call `.getTime()` the `-` operator takes numeric primitives. Other languages allow overloading operators but not Java.